# Solving a first order ODE with absolute value

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, absolute-value, initial-value-problems

In my class on differential equations, I have encountered the following initial value problem

> \begin{gather}
>  y' = 1 + |y-1| \\
>  y(0) = 0
> \end{gather}

I cannot solve this. The ODE is first order, but the absolute value confuses me as I cannot integrate or do anything like that with it, the equation is nonlinear and has me stuck. How would one find the solution to this? I know existence and uniqueness applies even though the absolute value is not smooth, but because it is Lipschitz continuous I know a smooth solution must exist which I cannot seem to find. Can anyone show me how to solve this? I thank all helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you solve each piece of
$$  y'(x) = \begin{cases}
1 + (y(x) - 1) &, y(x) \geq 1  \\
1 - (y(x) - 1) &, y(x) < 1  \\
\end{cases}  $$

Since the initial condition has $y(x) - 1 = -1 < 0$, you start in the second piece.  If you develop that solution forward, at what $x$ does $y(x) = 1$ occur?  Then what?

Comment: each piece looks like a first order linear ODE, so I solve each case starting with the second and then "glue" the two together so that I get a smooth solution?

Comment: @kroner Exactly.

Comment: Well, ... you follow a solution until it crosses $y(x) = 1$, then you (might) switch piece. (You might smoothly bounce off the line $y(x) = 1$ tangentially (like $1-x^2$), but this is rare.)  So you end up with a particular solution that follows one solution family for a while, then might switch to following the other family, and later may switch back and forth as many times as it does.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut if I did it correctly, should I get $$y(t) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
   -2e^{-t} + 2 & 0 \leq t < \ln(2) \\
   \frac{1}{2} e^t & \ln(2) \leq t\\
   \end{array} 
   \right. $$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut the problem is I cannot check this by machine as the function is piecewise

Comment: @kroner : Sometimes you're lucky enough that the two families of solutions are a single family or can be embedded into a single family (possibly with a parameter).  But, generally, your particular solutions are just piecewise segments of solutions from each family.

Comment: @EricTowers thank you, do you think my answer in the comments is the correct solution?

Comment: @kroner : That agrees with my work.

Comment: @EricTowers thank you very much for a great answer

Comment: @Aryadeva I do not understand, it is smooth and satisfies the condition $y(0)=0$

Comment: @Aryadeva : Kroner's answer has only one value at $y(1)$ because $1 > \ln(2)$.

Comment: @Aryadeva $\frac{e}{2}$

Comment: @Aryadeva : Do you understand that the absolute value function is defined piecewise and so is kroner's solution...

Comment: @Aryadeva : Do you understand that the domains for the two pieces are disjoint?

Answer (score 1):

My method of solving this differential equation is as follows:

---

1. Isolate the absolute-value term $\left|y-1\right|$.

   $y'=1+\left|y-1\right|$

   $y'-1=\left|y-1\right|$

---

2. Eliminate the absolute-value symbols around $y-1$ while also
   applying a $\pm$ to $y'-1$.

   $y'-1=\left|y-1\right|$

   $\pm\left(y'-1\right)=y-1$

---

3. Rewrite the equation into 2 separate equations to accommodate for
   the $\pm$.

   $\pm\left(y'-1\right)=y-1$

   $\begin{Bmatrix} y'-1=y-1\\
   -\left(y'-1\right)=y-1 \end{Bmatrix},\ y\left(0\right)=0$

---

From there you can solve each differential equation individually.